# How To Update TOR Software On Debian Linux

Tags: configuration, relays

I am running my tor relay via Debian Linux, and am wondering, how do I update the TOR software via the command line? I am not running the tor browser software here, just the tor software for running relays?

It might be important to note my relay is running in a Debian Linux virtual machine which is running via VirtualBox. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the installed `tor` package from the Debian repository this way:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y --only-upgrade tor
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do it from a liveboot or something?